# Python Module installation via pip does not work and shows error message

Tags: ssl, installation, pip, python-3.11

I have installed Python 3.11 on my Windows Notebook per downloaded installer from python.com.
When I try to install modules in the windows command line I receive an error message and the module has not been installed.
For example:

```
pip install pandas
```

the following error message occurs:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/9e/71/756a1be6bee0209d8c0d8c5e3b9fc72c00373f384a4017095ec404aec3ad/pandas-2.0.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)')))
```

I have tried python.exe pip install [module], python pip install [module] and python3 pip install [module]
But nothing works.
Also changing from Wifi to LAN connection has not helped.

I have Ubuntu running on another Notebook. There I can install in the terminal modules per pip install [module] without any problems and assume to do it in the same way on my Windows Notebook.

Comment: This is answered if you didn't see it [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311305/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-while-using-pip?rq=2[herestrong text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311305/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-while-using-pip?rq=2))