# Python PIP installation error related to SSL

Tags: python, installation, pip

With the below pip command I am trying to install the docai-py python library

pip install --index-url=internal company repositary --trusted-host=internal company url docai-py

There are a few dependent libraries which it is installed successfully but while installed the dependent package seqeval, the following error was raised

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open

    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))

  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1244, in request

    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1290, in _send_request

    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in endheaders

    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output

    self.send(msg)

  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 966, in send

    self.connect()

  File "c:\users\puthran1\pycharmprojects\python37-64bit\lib\site-packages\setuptools\ssl_support.py", line 191, in connect

    self.sock = ctx.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=actual_host)

  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket

    session=session

  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create

    self.do_handshake()

  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake

    self._sslobj.do_handshake()

ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)
```

I tried couple of things suggested on the internet but not able to fix it.

Any suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED" error while using PIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311305/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-while-using-pip)